# powershell count number of defined files in defined subfolder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have N different directories (titles are random and do not have test pattern in string)

```
C:\Folder\test1\file.txt
C:\Folder\test2\file.txt
...
C:\Folder\testN\file.txt
```

I want to count number of file.txt files in Folder dir in all `test1..testN` subdirectories using powershell, in example `C:\Folder\*\file.txt`

I started with below code, but it counts all files

```
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem C:\Folder | Measure-Object ).Count;
```

Could you pls help?

Updated: I dont need file.txt files in `test1...N` subfolders, only in `test1...N` folder In example - `C:\Folder\*\file.txt`, but not `C:\Folder\*\abc\file.txt`

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0):

You're close, this should get you the total count of `file.txt` files any folder C:\Folder\Test*

```
Write-Host ( Get-ChildItem C:\folder\test* -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Include file.txt | Measure-Object ).Count
```

Comment: thanks, but I dont need all file.txt files, but only in test1...N folder (no subfolders either)

Answer (score 0):

Edited: I think I got what you want now.

```
Clear-Host
$TestPath = "C:\Folder"
$FileCnt = 0

$Dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path "$TestPath" -Directory 
ForEach ($Dir in $Dirs) {
 $FileCnt += (Get-ChildItem -Path "$($($Dir).FullName)\*.*" -Filter "file.txt"  | 
   Measure-Object).count
}
$FileCnt
```

PMental's solution below is more elegant but this also works.
HTH

Comment: thanks, but I dont need all .txt files, but only file.txt in test1...N folder (no subfolders either)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question properly, you would like to get the count of all *.txt files inside a rootfolder, 1 level deep, where the direct parent foldername is called `testX` (`X` is a sequence number).

You have a structure like this:

```
C:\FOLDER
+---test1
|   |   file1.txt
|   |
|   \---abc
|           file1.txt
|
+---test2
|       file1.txt
|
\---test3
        file1.txt
```

For that you can use

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Folder' -Filter '*.txt' -Depth 1 | 
    Where-Object { $_.Directory.Name -match '^test\d+$' }).Count
```

which in the example structure above returns `3`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
(Get-ChildItem C:\Folder -Filter file.txt -File -Recurse -Depth 1 | Measure-Object).Count
```

or if you only want text files from the subfolders and not from C:\Folder itself, this one:

```
$Path = 'C:\Folder'
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter file.txt -File -Recurse -Depth 1 | 
    Where-Object PSParentPath -notlike "*::$Path"
($Files | Measure-Object).Count
```

Edited: Edited to only count "file.txt" files.

Comment: This works if you change the *.txt to file.txt as OP stated.

Comment: @RetiredGeek Ah, yes if he actually only wants file.txt-files that needs to change, added an edit detailing that too.

Edit: And indeed he states that in another answer, updated my answer.